# Decrypt file from external file location

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm facing the following issue. The customer intends to provide encrypted import files on his SFTP. The Automation Studio interface and [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_file_transfer_activity.htm&type=5) both state:

> Use Manage File, formerly the Download option, to unzip or decrypt a
>   file in the Enhanced FTP directory.

**My question:** Is it possible to decrypt or unzip files from an external SFTP Location with the Manage File option or is this really limited to the enhanced FTP of the Marketing Cloud?

If it is indeed limited to the the Enhanced FTP has anyone found a workaround?

Thanks in advance,
Stephan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to piece an environment together to test it. Here's the answer for the benefit of the community:

1. Yes, it works from an external file location
2. The transfer result (unzipped and/or decrypted file) ends up in the default import folder of the SFMC Enhanced FTP.
3. In result the solution requires the external file location + Enhanced FTP to get files into the Marketing Cloud